# How to split a List by a condition into two lists

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming, pattern-matching, folding

I'm trying to write in functional way the body for this function:

```
grouping[T](xs: List[T], rule: T => Boolean): Tuple2[List[T], List[T]]
```

in order to use it like this:

```
println(grouping(List(1, 2, 100, 3, 4, 501, 12), (x: Int) => x >= 100))
println(grouping(List('A', 'C', 'Z', 'T', 'O', 'P', 'N', 'M', 'Y'), (x: 
Char) => x >= 'J'))
```

and get:

```
(List(100, 501), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 12))
(List(Z, T, O, P, N, M, Y),List(A, C))
```

Comment: you should look first into the List API, and see if there's any method that works for you. It's easier, and faster than wait for an answer. Using an IDEA is really easy. otherwise you can always look fot the scaladocs: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partition(p:A=%3EBoolean):(Repr,Repr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` provides the [`partition`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partition(p:A=%3EBoolean):(Repr,Repr)) method which does just that:

```
List(1, 2, 100, 3, 4, 501, 12).partition(_ >= 100)
```

and returns:

```
(List(100, 501), List(1, 2, 3, 4, 12))
```

---

From the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partition(p:A=%3EBoolean):(Repr,Repr)):

> def partition(p: (T) => Boolean): (List[T], List[T])
>
> Partitions this traversable collection in two traversable collections according to a predicate.
>   partition(p: (T) => Boolean): (List[T], List[T])
>   Partitions this traversable collection in two traversable collections according to a predicate.

---

And we can encapsulate it in a function which takes a predicate in input:

```
def grouping[T](xs: List[T], rule: T => Boolean): (List[T], List[T]) = {
  xs.partition(rule)
}
```

to apply it this way:

```
grouping(List(1, 2, 100, 3, 4, 501, 12), (i: Int) => i >= 100)
grouping(List('A', 'C', 'Z', 'T', 'O', 'P', 'N', 'M', 'Y'), (x: Char) => x >= 'J')
```